# What's the difference between these two simple codes? More specifically, what is this if statement used for?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading a book on Python and it's presenting this code:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(a, end='')
    if args:
        print()
```

I'm confused what the point of *if args* is when the code below also shows the same output.

```
def myfunc(*args):
    for a in args:
        print(a, end='')
```

Comment: The second print completes the line by printing a \n, in unix, or a \n\r in Windows. Just add print('hello') to the  end of second script to see what happens.

Comment: Call these two different functions ***twice*** in a row, and you'll see the difference. (Newline at the end or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions of your function print the list of arguments it receives.

The `end=''` parameter makes sure that the `\n` character is not appended for each print, as would happen by default, printing a line for every argument.

In this way you will have an output like this

```
arg1arg2...argN<noNewline>
```

(all the arguments are joined with not even a space separating them). With no `end=''`, instead, you would have had

```
arg1
arg2
...
argN
```

---

Since you might want a trailing newline, in the end you call `print()`, which just prints a newline. **But** only if the args list is not empty (`if args:`), in order to avoid a "strange" empty line even when no arguments are present.

Answer (score 1):

`if args` will be True if any arguments exist.

`print()` just prints a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

`*args` allows you forward as many arguments to a function as possible. `*args` always returns `set`. You are looping over the items in the `set`, and print each one **without** new line at the end. In the first code, the condition will return `True` as long as `*args` is not `None`.

```
def function(*args):
    if *args:
        return f'{args} is not None!`
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example prints a newline character more if args contains one ore more arguments.
I think it's just there to make the output a bit prettier and it is not really important.